# Any way to use Google Api without every-time authentication?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I tried to use the API on python in a autorun on a PC. But I can't because every time the program starts, it asks me about the authorization code.
This is my code:

```
client_secret_file = "client_secret.json"
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Are you only accessing your own account? Will you not be accessing accounts of other users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becouse you are using the YouTube API you can not use a service account you will need to use Oauth2.

Oauth2 can return something called a refresh token, if you store this token your code can then access the refresh token the next time it runs and use the refresh token to request a new access token this way it will not need to ask you every time it runs to access your data.

```
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

The only offical sample that includes refresh token that i know if is here [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python)  you will need to alter it for YouTube but the auth code is really all you need just plug that int your code and you should be GTG

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this using [Service](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#service-accounts) Account.

https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#service-accounts

Service account are technically pre authorized by the developer.

IF the API does not support Service account( in some cases) then you can try [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) where you have a consent for asking the owner of the account if you can access

Comment: I am using the python API, sorry for no saying before

Comment: Updated the link for service account details of the python Google API

Comment: Author apears to be using the YouTube API,  the youtube api does not support service accounts.   This answer will not help.