# What will I have to do to upload YouTube videos on multiple YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have multiple YouTube channels (brand accounts). I want to upload YouTube videos to different channels accordingly. But the only doubt is that I don't know the mechanism to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: I know how to upload video to YouTube, but am facing the issue of uploading videos to my multiple YouTube channels (brand account). I just don't know how to begin with that approach.

Comment: First get acquainted with [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started); then read the guide [Upload a Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video). It may well be a long way ahead before achieving your goal; you need patience and perseverance.

Comment: @stvar Thanks for the reply. I know how to upload video to YouTube but I just don't know how to upload to multiple YouTube Channels(brand account). Otherwise I know how to use YouTube API

Comment: Then this is the answer to your question: [YouTube Data API with multiple accounts using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201331/8327971). Even if Python is not your implementation language, that answer should help you well understanding the basic logic of managing multiple credentials data sets.

Comment: @stvar Thank You.Yeah I use python for Youtube api