# Program activating the wrong google cloud platform project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api

I was following [this](https://learndataanalysis.org/how-to-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-data-api-in-python/) tutorial on how to upload videos to youtube, and it worked perfectly until I decided to switch projects (let's call them `Project 1` and `Project 2`)  because of a bad name (let's call them `Project 1` and `Project 2`) that would definitely bug me later on.

Then a problem occurred, where even though I had changed the client secret json file, it would still call `Project 1`. After a good hour of programmer pain, I tried deleting the OAuth 2.0 client id, thinking it would default to `Project 2`'s OAuth. Unfortunately for me, that did *not* work and now both `Project 1` and `Project 2` are broken. Recreating the OAuth does nothing.

As you can probably tell, I'm not the best programmer, and this is the first time I've ever worked with this kinda stuff, and there doesn't seem to be anything online at all about this online at all. I would assume it would be something to do with stored cache or something along those lines, but I'm too scared to mess up my project even more, so I decided to create a StackOverflow account for the first time and ask some more experienced devs.

Any help at all would be super appreciated, and if you require anything I didn't add in this post, or think there's something I could improve please let me know as I'm quite new to this.

(code is in the linked tutorial as to not clutter the post)

Comment: What error do you get when you run the program?

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [YouTube Data API with multiple accounts using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201331/8327971).

Comment: @stvar That seems to be asking how to use one cloud platform project for multiple youtube channels, no? My problem is switching to a new one

Comment: @AlfonsMuñoz none, it (did) work perfectly fine, just on the wrong project. Deleting the project does nothing, and it still worked fine for some reason.

Comment: @Eden Gibson: One project or many is the same problem, only that the client secret JSON files must be managed properly. The mechanism is there: you have to have the credentials data saved separately for each Google project and YouTube channel. There is the answer to your question -- you only have to adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of effort looking, I found out that the .pickle file the tutorial code creates stores your login information. I deleted it and it works just fine now.